# Can't import EasyDialogs - ImportError: No module named _Dlg

Tags: python, user-interface

I'm trying to use the EasyDialogs python module to produce some simple dialog boxes for my python script on OSX. Whenever I try and import the EasyDialogs module I get the following error:

```
>>> import EasyDialogs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/6.2/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/EasyDialogs.py", line 24, in <module>
    from Carbon.Dlg import GetNewDialog, SetDialogItemText, GetDialogItemText, ModalDialog
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/6.2/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/Carbon/Dlg.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _Dlg import *
ImportError: No module named _Dlg
```

I've tried doing `easy_install Carbon`, as I thought it may be due to some issue with the Carbon package for python, but that hasn't helped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the paths in your traceback, you appear to be using a 64-bit Enthought Python Distribution.  The `EasyDialogs` module uses various OS X Carbon interfaces, many of which OS X only provides 32-bit versions and have been deprecated by Apple.  For this reason, the Python `Carbon` wrapper and `EasyDialogs` modules are deprecated in Python 2 and have been removed in Python 3.  While they may work in 32-bit mode, you should avoid using them in new code.  There are other alternatives available: `Tkinter` in the standard library, various cross platform GUI frameworks (see [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming)).  For more simple dialogs, you could also use the [osax](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/doc/osax-manual/03_examples.html) package in [appscript](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/appscript/) to use the `User Interaction` suite of AppleScript's `Standard Additions`.