# Open a directory dialog using python

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing

I am trying to create a simple file dialog (preferably the system one) for use with a local server.

I can't use Tkinter because it has to be run in a sub process and the dialog box will not stay open on Mac in a sub process.  I can not use a thread because it will lock up eventually.

Is there any way to open up a system file dialog WITHOUT using Tkinter.

This first file is a self sufficient working version of the behaviour I want (ignore none type error at the very end)

```
import Tkinter as tk
import threading
from tkFileDialog import askdirectory

def createDialog(communicationQueue):
    dia = Dialog(communicationQueue)
    dia.show()

class Dialog():

    def __init__(self, communicationQueue):
        self.communicationQueue = communicationQueue

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.overrideredirect(True)
        self.root.geometry("0x0+%d+%d" % (0, 0))
        self.root.withdraw()

        print 'creating root'
        print 'Root Created'

        self.root.update()
        self.root.deiconify()

        print 'asking directory'

        t = threading.Thread(target = self.show)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

        self.root.mainloop()
        print 'Directory found!'

    def show(self):
        print "show dialog"

        self.root.lift()
        name = askdirectory()
        print name
        self.communicationQueue.put(name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    createDialog(None)
    print "Blocking!"
```

This file combined with the first file attempts to use Tkinter in a sub process

```
import time

from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def _createDialog(communicationQueue):
    from src.utilities import fileDialog
    fileDialog.createDialog(communicationQueue)
    print 'method!'

def showDirectoryDialog():
    """A blocking method that returns the directory path to a selected directory"""
    communicationQueue = Queue()
    p = Process(target = _createDialog, args = (communicationQueue,))
    p.start()

    count = 0
    while (communicationQueue.empty() and count <= 5):
        print "waiting"
        time.sleep(5)
        count = count + 1
    print 'Process should start'
    time.sleep(1)
    print 'Thread should have slept for 1 second'
    return name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = showDirectoryDialog()
    print name
```

If someone can get this working On mac or at least figure out why the root window stays open until askDirectory() is called I would be very greatful

Comment: are you just targetting Mac, or does this need to work on other OSes as well?

Comment: I would like to target windows and linux.
But if there are OSX only solutions they will be welcomed as well.

Comment: well, I had found [`EasyDialogs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/easydialogs.html), but for some reason I can't get it working on my MacPorts version of Python. It's only in 2.X, but if you can get it working it looks quite, well ... easy. Check out http://pymotw.com/2/EasyDialogs/index.html for some examples.

Comment: it appears that it is not working on my computer either...
Something about an import error.  But thank you very much for the suggestion!

Comment: can't get it working on a fresh install of python.org 2.7.8, nor on the system python (2.7.2) for Mt Lion. Strange...

Comment: Ahh - check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159194/cant-import-easydialogs-importerror-no-module-named-dlg. It's deprecated, so I guess any issues with it aren't getting fixed. Anyways, as an alternative to Tkinter, have you considered PyQt or PySide? They're pretty heavy dependencies, but they're cross-platform, and AFAIK can tap into the native file dialogs. Not sure about thread safety, but you can certainly try...

Comment: I'll look into those I am trying to not have many libraries so that other people who use this will not have to install everything and the wazu...

I might try java because at least in java opening a file dialog is super simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking on how to solve this problem...

I ended up using java.
Python file dialog ended up being very difficult to play with.  It has some very weird requirements and requires you to create a second window that you then have to hide so it does not fulfill what I need it to do in a way that is intuitive for a user.  (Or even intuitive for the programmer)

Java has a build in file dialog system that is easier to use. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html

But regardless it appears that mac has problem popping up file dialogs multiple times from the same program regardless of the language. These problems do not appear on windows.

So that is also something to look at if your solution is cross platform.

Answer (score 1):

The following python function will bring up a MacOS file save dialog. The arguments provide the default location and filename

```
from AppKit import NSSavePanel, NSApp
from Foundation import NSURL

def save_dialog(directory, filename):
    panel = NSSavePanel.savePanel()
    panel.setTitle_("Save your document")
    myUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_isDirectory_(directory, True)
    panel.setDirectoryURL_(myUrl)
    panel.setNameFieldStringValue_(filename)
    NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps_(True)
    ret_value = panel.runModal()
    if ret_value:
        return panel.filename()
    else:
        return ''
```

For an Open dialog, see the documentation on NSOpenPanel (which is even simpler.)